How do the contemporary sources advise that one starts praying shmoneh esrei of shacharit at hanetz hachama?
I understand that as Halachipedia puts it

The ideal mitzvah is to start praying shmoneh esrei of shacharit at
hanetz hachama (sunrise).

Question part 1: How precise does one have to be with the time of hanetz? Even where sunrise is observable, if one is a minute after the computed time (on e.g. Myzmanim.com), is that no longer “starting at hanetz”?
Question part 2: My Rav said that there are opinions that it is better to daven a little after  the computed time to be sure that one is not davenning before  hanetz hachama.
So please tell how the contemporary sources advise that one starts praying shmoneh esrei of shacharit at hanetz hachama?

It's clearly impossible https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13226/759 and would have been more impossible in the past. You're left with two logical options: 1) halachically speaking hanetz/shkiya is a time period of some duration, not a moment; 2) only rarely will you ever get it right (Berachot 9b זימנא חדא סמך גאולה לתפלה ולא פסיק חוכא מפומיה כוליה יומא) but apparently it's worth trying even if you end up too early.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78759/davening-neitz-in-the-olden-days?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment237340_78759

Worth noting some rishonim/geonim held that the ideal mitzva isn't to start the amida at hanetz but rather to start shema (or perhaps its blessings) at hanetz. That's not how Shulchan Arukh rules, but it's another reason to push in the later direction, beyond imprecision of measurement. Conversely, others hold that the "ideal" thing isn't starting the amida specifically at hanetz, but rather having shema be sometime before hanetz and the amida be anytime after it. Accordingly, the best thing to do is a have a very long Geulah blessing.

The minyan that I attended used the algorithm developped by US Naval observatory from 1940s. It is subject to some error. Many Jewish calendars use a similar calculation.

@YDJ The US Navy made an algorithm to calculate halachic times?

@DoubleAA they developed the algorithm for calculation the time of sunrise and the time of sunset. The halachic times are calculated based on these.

@YDJ And how are the minyan's rabbi's preferred hanetz times calculated from the naval times? That's the relevant psak question.

The practice of Rav Chaim Kanievsky zt"l according to this book written by his grandsonwas to daven within a few minutes after netz. He held (and so did the Chazon Ish) that that is considered davening at netz.
On a practical note, it isn't really possible to time netz to the second, as it depends on the visibility of the sun, which varies depending on altitude and humidity. (Water causes light to curve, so water molecules in the air can make the sun's light more curvy, meaning it is visible for longer while supposedly being below the horizon. So you would also have to calculate humidity between your position and the horizon.) You would be better off giving it a few minutes so you don't daven too early by mistake. However, b'dieved one would still be yotzei since it is after "alos hashachar".

"within a few minutes after netz" How many minutes? How did he define/calculate "netz" for starting those "few minutes"? This answer is too ambiguous to be put into practice.

How do you know this was RSYCK's practice?  (FWIW I heard it as "+/- 2 minutes from netz" which is also ambiguous though less so AND notably different from your version in allowing "before" too. That why we need something more concrete than "I heard" for deciding halacha.)
