# Skipping to Daven Netz Alone

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, shacharis-morning-prayer, tefillah-betzibbur, hanetz-sunrise

This is somewhat related to a [previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57437/8899) I asked.

When praying with a minyan, one may skip portions of the liturgy in order to "sync up" with the rest of the group for Shema and Amidah. So reciting the order of liturgy < praying with the community.

Additionally, there are well regarded opinions that allow for praying solitary in order to pray the Amidah at netz (of course, there are caveats to when this is applicable). So praying with the community < praying at daybreak.

If a person is trying to pray ALONE at netz, but realizes that they won't reach it if they read all of the liturgy, are they permitted to skip portions of the service to reach Amidah at the appropriate time?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is permitted to skip in Pesukei deZimrah, just like in tzibbur, since davening with Netz is compared to davening with tzibbur (according to some opinions even better). **Source:** Ishei Yisroel 13:7 (currently available for free [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=181332&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15854675982792782&pagenum=150)), quoting Zeh HaSulchan 1:52 (currently available for free [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=11729&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=15854675982792782&pagenum=11)).