# Allowed to skip certain parts of shacharis in order to say shacharis shemoneh esrei before chatzos?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer

In the Artscroll siddur it says if a person is afraid he will not catch up to the tzibbur fast enough in order to start Shemoneh Esrei with them, he is allowed to skip everything except certain required things, for example Baruch She'amar, Ashrei, Yishtabach and Shema and its brachos.

If a person does not daven with a minyan because he lives too far, and he woke up very late and was negligent in doing so, should he skip everything except the required things mentioned in Artscroll so that he can daven Shemoneh Esrei before Chatzos?

Comment: Almost a dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80258/9643

Comment: Once Zeman Tefila passes I do not think this question is relevant. Zeman Tefila for Shacharis is way before Chatzos.

Comment: @GershonGold absolutely wrong.  the time for shacharis is up until chatzos b'dieved

Comment: @Ploni it's either a dupe or not a dupe, there is no "almost."

Comment: Then you should put a source for that in your question.

Comment: What’s unclear about this? You can skip parts of davening to daven Tefillah b’tzibbur; may one do so to daven b’zmanah? Seems straightforward to me. And someone please enlighten me: where in this question does it ask for a Halachos ruling? Entirely on-topic to me.

Answer (score 3):

The time for tfila in the morning is, *a priori* (*lehathila*), up to the fourth halachic hour (a third of the daytime) and, after the fact if you missed the time, up to halachic noon (it is an explicit Mishna in [Brakhot 4:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.4.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Therefore, if after the fact, you are at risk of missing the *zman tfila*, you should skip the parts mentioned in the artscroll siddur.

There is a question whether to skip shema in such a scenario and you should ask your rav as there are different opinions (some believe the order of prayer should not be changed). See [here](http://www.practicalhalacha.com/c/6177/prayers?view=halachot) (mid-page) for one possible approach

> You must say the shema no later than the end of the third halachic
>   hour of the day in the morning. If you did not say it in time:
>
> - If it is before the fourth halachic hour of the day, say the entire shacharit service, as long as you will complete the amida before the
>     end of the fourth halachic hour.
> - If it is after the fourth halachic hour of the day but before the end of the sixth halachic hour of the day, say birchot ha'shachar (and
>     you may also say korbanot) and then skip all of shacharit up to the
>     amida, which you should say as soon as possible.

And next time you should set an alarm clock :->