# For the start of the day, is "sunset" astronomical or visible?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, astronomy

Yesterday was the equinox and I noticed that the day was longer than 12 hours according to the (secular) sunrise/sunset times.  Curious, I did some investigation.  One reason for the difference is how we measure -- the equinox is based on when the *center* of the sun is visible while sunrise/sunset times are based on when the *top edge* is visible.  That only accounts for a couple minutes; though; the bigger factor is [atmospheric refracion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_refraction) (discussed in simpler terms [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/equinox-not-equal.html)), which, in a nutshell, means that the sun is visible to us in the sky *even when it is below the horizon*, for several minutes.

This made me wonder about the effect on *halachic* times.  [This article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3240769/jewish/Why-Are-Shabbat-Candles-Lit-18-Minutes-Before-Sunset.htm) says that the *halacha* is that Shabbat begins at sunset, though we add time for safety.  I know that, *l'hatchila*, we add (usually) 18 minutes before the start of Shabbat or Yom Tov to provide a cushion.  That's more than enough to account for any false effects due to refraction, but I've also been told that, *b'dieved*, if one is running late and has to cut into those 18 minutes, it's still ok so long as you actually began Shabbat/Yom Tov before the end of those 18 minutes, at sunset.  And therein lies my question.

Regardless of how we *halachically* [define sunset](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47449/472), we might see the sun above the horizon and conclude that it is not yet sunset *when the sun has actually already set*.  Does this mean that the day has in fact started -- we go by where the sun is, not where it appears to be -- and if you light at the 15th of the 18 minutes you're kindling fire on Shabbat?  Or, *halachically*, is sunset based on what we *see*, not what we now know happens scientifically?

I know there's discussion (somewhere) of Shabbat times if you're in the mountains or have an obstructed view of the horizon, and maybe that's relevant here.  That's a more localized situation, while atmospheric refraction happens everywhere all the time, so I don't know if that makes it a different case.

Does Shabbat really start sometime during the 18 minutes?

Comment: I can't imagine halakha would account for this phenomenon no one knew about till recently. (Same with the 8 minute delay it takes sunlight to reach Earth.) Think of it like eating bacteria: what you see is what you get, even if science says otherwise.

Comment: @DoubleAA well, I doubt *rishonim* would have accounted for it (though I don't know a lot about the history of science), but we have *halacha* today about other modern things like the Internet, so it seems possible that somebody modern has dealt with this.

Comment: Actually, according to [the abstract of this paper](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-44-27-5624), western science knew about it in the second century BCE and Ptolemy modeled it 300 years later.  (I haven't read the paper yet.)

Comment: Look forward to reading that after yom tov. Chag Yavesh veSameach!

Comment: Usually Halachah works with what a person sees with the naked eye regardless of what is scientifically happening (as you suggested). The other consideration is that the Halachic next day starts when 3 medium stars come out according to many poskim. The whole sunset thing was adhered to by more and more poskim because of the great awe and fear of breaking Shabbos. (Shulchan Aruch HaRav writes Shabbos starts when it gets dark, but he changed it to sunset later.) So the 18 minute cushion is in some ways a cushion on a cushion/doubt. There is a lot of info on it. Great question, Good Yom Tov all.

Comment: I look forward to investigating this more after Yom Tov.  I know this wasn't the best time to ask the question, but it's when I had it. :-)  Chag sameach all!

Comment: *Bein Hashmashot* is extremely complex. I just did a shiur on this 2 days ago. Apparently, there's a "middle ground" that defines this period as defining "darkness" but not actually defining th new Hebrew date. I'll see if I can gather the various materials that I found and summarize some answer. I will say that there is no consensus, though.